# why skype is not available on messengers like pidgin

Tags: skype, instant-messaging, pidgin, protocol

i really like pidgin, empathy etc. (especially pidgin) because they gather all accounts like xmpp, msn etc. together except **skype**. i know skype uses a proprietary protocol but so does msn and it is available on pidgin. is it that hard to "put" skype on pidgin or alike messengers? what is the reason that skype is not implemented in pidgin?

note: i know there is a plugin for pidgin to support skype but it requires the official skype client to be installed and running. pretty useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i know skype uses a proprietary protocol but so does msn and it is available on pidgin. is it that hard to "put" skype on pidgin or alike messengers? what is the reason that skype is not implemented in pidgin?

The difference is that such protocols as MSNP, OSCAR (ICQ/AIM) and Yahoo Messenger use plain text – the commands and data can easily be seen using a TCP sniffer such as Wireshark. It is possible to obtain some information from the official client software as well. Parts of OSCAR have been publicly documented by AOL itself.

On the other hand, both the Skype client and [protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype_protocol) are highly obfuscated and protected against reverse engineering. There is some analysis available (for example, [Vanilla Skype](http://www.recon.cx/en/f/vskype-part1.pdf) and [part 2](http://www.recon.cx/en/f/vskype-part2.pdf)) but it's far from enough.

Comment: i guess also most traffic is encrypted in skype.

Comment: @sterz: _All_ of it.